# Keyboard shortcut to sign out of Gmail

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut that will sign me out of Gmail?

Comment: Can you tell what operating system/browser do you use ?

Comment: Windows 7 - Google Chrome

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Unfortunately, there isn't a shortcut to use in Gmail for signing out.**

But you can copy the sign out link `https://mail.google.com/mail/?logout&hl=en` and assign a keyboard shortcut to it, or add it to your bookmarks.

**Example:**

Assuming you are using Google Chrome, use [ClickLess](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aifjjioohifiaokjpjcbbmopgnpjajgl?ct=author#), a Chrome extension, to assign a shortcut for the link of sign out, which is mentioned above.

**Go to the options of this extension** and add the shortcut.

Now whenever you need to sign out. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, a small windows will pop out, press now <kbd>s</kbd> which is the shortcut key for signing out from Gmail.

[image]

Comment: Okay. That sounds like a good workaround. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It really does work!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Opera, add the above mentioned URI to one of your speed dials (first 9). Then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (where N = digit 1-9) when you are on Gmail to sign out.

I added this on my 1st speed dial, so now I can easily sign out by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

Comment: Please fully read the question, comments, and already provided answers prior to  adding a new answer, especially to old questions.  Back in Aug 2011 almost a year before this post the asker stated that this was in Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

A trick better than shortcut key is just to paste this link on the address bar to sign out...  ***

> https://mail.google.com/mail/?logout&hl=en

---